# Setting python version for live-py and python-excecute-file (SPC m c c) in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, python

Im new to Emacs, i hope i didn't miss anything simple.

My configuration is:

- OS - OSX sierra 10.12.6.
- Emacs - 25.3.1 (Emacs-emacs-plus from homebrew)
- python - trying to set 2.7.14.

I want to make myself a decent developing environment for python, there is one problem i'm not sure how to solve.

I want emacs (and all layers) to use python from this path: `/usr/local/bin/python2`

I seted in .spacemacs file at `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()`:

```
    ;; python:
    (setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/python2")
    (setq py-python-command "/usr/local/bin/python2")
    (setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
```

Now when i execute `run-python`:
[image: python path run-pyton.]
 it works well and start with desired version.

But when i'm editing python file in `python-mode` and trying to launch either `live-py` or `python-execute-file` it opens up in system default python version.
i.e.:
[image: py-live mode.]
different path.

What i am doing wrong?

Thank

Comment: What's `python-execute-file`?  I don't seem to have a command with that name (spacemacs branch `devel`).

Answer (score 1):

`SPC h d f run-python RET` and `SPC h d f live-py-mode` will tell you that those two commands are provided by different files (`python.el` and `live-py-mode.el` respectively).  This will take you to the source code for `live-py-mode`: `SPC SPC find-library RET live-py-mode RET`.  If you look at the variables near the top of that file, you'll see that setting `live-py-mode` like this is what you need:

`(setq live-py-version "python2")`

Comment: trying `SPC h d f live-py-mode RET`
i keep getting this message:
`simpler-helm-bookmark-keybindings: Symbol’s value as variable is void: helm-bookmark-map`

@Croad Langshan

Comment: @MasterSprinkler Looks like you might need to update your spacemacs: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9549

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Then I figured it out that I can use *`C-u SPC m c c`*, and then, for example, using *python3 python_script.py* to execute python_script.py with specified *python3* rather than the system default *python*. However, I still don't know how to set the default version as python3.